# Software for creating a definition library

Tags: math-software

For a while I've been looking for some kind of software that will let me create and cross-reference definitions. The way I imagine this working would be, for instance: I create a file named "Hopf algebra", I type in "A Hopf algebra over a field k is a k-bialgebra such that..." and follow with the definition of a Hopf algebra, and things like "bialgebra" and "field" would be links to those definitions. Essentially something like a DIY maths encyclopedia. Bonus things would be allowing me to put things into categories (e.g. ring theory vs. group theory) and colour-coding, and some manner of LaTeX support would be pretty essential.

I cannot be the only one who's had this idea, but so far all my Google searches have been turning up empty - I figure there's some key word I'm missing. Has anyone heard of something like this before?

Edit: What I'm looking for is a sort of better-organised and better-crossref'd software version of the giant stack of index cards I use right now, not a wiki or anything communal like that.

Answer (score 2):

http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page is something like this for group theory.  There is also the [nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/HomePage).  Both of them run on wiki software; do you have something else in mind?

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I was hoping to have something non-communal. The point is to write up the definitions I need in my own words and not to use an already existing encyclopedia - a sort of software version of the mess of index cards I use at the moment - so a wiki isn't really what I need.

Comment: You could set up your own personal wiki using something like Instiki, which has LaTeX support: http://www.instiki.org/show/HomePage

Comment: That might be worth posting as an answer (or at least editing into your answer body).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Wikipedia with [Google SideWiki](http://www.google.com/sidewiki/intl/en/index.html) or any other software that lets you annotate a site.

Comment: I would be wary of using site annotation software, including Google SideWiki. At this point, I don't see it being something that takes off and any services that are used for this might end up going away with no way to retrieve your data. A better alternative if you want to go this route is a browser plugin that stores your annotations locally.

Answer (score 0):

Why not a database with LibreOffice?

Or something more LaTeX oriented as [TeXmacs](http://texmacs.org): it comes with fantastic LaTeX quality rendering, it can link documents (not sure how far though) and embed mathematics output from third party software.